# JMeter - o.a.j.f.FileToString: Could not read open

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a huge http request payload so I put them in a file and tried to read the file and place content using the `FileToString` function.

When I run the JMeter it's showing an error in log, but if I take and open the file in the log with text editor it is opening the file.

HTTP Request - Body Data:-

```
${__FileToString('C:/Users/Desktop/company/hugemodify.txt',,)}
```

Logs :-

```
018-07-19 07:34:08,336 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: API QA Thread  Group - Modify 1-1
2018-07-19 07:34:08,341 WARN o.a.j.f.FileToString: Could not read open: 'C:/Users/Desktop/company/hugemodify.txt' 
2018-07-19 07:34:09,885 WARN o.a.j.f.FileToString: Could not read open: 'C:/Users/Desktop/company/hugemodify.txt' 
2018-07-19 07:34:10,120 WARN o.a.j.f.FileToString: Could not read open: 'C:/Users/Desktop/company/hugemodify.txt' 
2018-07-19 07:34:10,357 WARN o.a.j.f.FileToString: Could not read open: 'C:/Users/Desktop/company/hugemodify.txt' 
2018-07-19 07:34:11,776 WARN o.a.j.f.FileToString: Could not read open: 'C:/Users/Desktop/company/hugemodify.txt' 
2018-07-19 07:34:12,016 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: API QA Thread  Group - Modify 1-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning happens when file isn't exists or you don't have permissions to read it

I'm seeing from logs that you are trying to get from Desktop folder, but without stating your user name. normally link should be replaced with your **LoginUserName**:

```
    ${__FileToString("C:/Users/LoginUserName/Desktop/company/hugemodify.txt",,)}
```

**Edit**

Change to using double quotes in file parameter

Comment: it has username, just removed to hide identity.Thanks for your reply.I dont know why it is not working.

Comment: @sunleo are you logged in with the same username? you can test function with links using Function Helper Dialog (Ctrl +Shift +F11)

Comment: Man problem with single quote

Comment: pls remove single quote and update the answer I will accept it.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer doesn't work in `Apache JMeter v5.1.1`.

In `Apache JMeter v5.1.1`, double quotes is not required (**even if the file path has a space**).

As mentioned by @user7294900, use **Function Helper Dialog** to get the right command .The keyboard shortcut is: **`Ctrl + Shift + F1`**